# Changing the name of the remote repo in Bazaar

Tags: rename, bazaar

I want to change the name of my checkout repo in Bazaar but I am not sure if it will create any problems if I just rename the folder. Is there any way to do this safely ?

Answer (score 2):

You can **safely change the directory name of your local repository**.
The only concern is that if you publish this repository for other user, as a shared folder for example.

But maybe I misunderstand the question ...
So if you speak about **renaming the remote repository**, well, you just need to `bind` all local checkout to this new address.

`Bind` command documentation:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-reference/bind-help.html

Comment: Yeah that is fine. I normally leave a symlink in place pointing to the new location, for in case the old location is still referenced..